# Sort image files in recent order

Tags: php, image, sorting, directory

Asked this but still not getting the right code that fits in with this one. The reason why i don't want to change the code is because the pagination system works.

I've tried the `arsort`, `rsort` and many other sorting functions but the images still don't show the  recent images that were in my directory.

```
<?php
$page = "";
$record_count = 100;
$dir = ('uploaded/');
$offset = ($page-1)*$record_count;
$files = glob("uploaded/*.*");
$files_filter  = array(arsort($files,$record_count));//made sorting changes here
$images = array(arsort(glob($dir . '*.*', GLOB_BRACE)));

$latestimage = $images[0];

    $large = '';  
    $allow = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png', 'JPEG', 'JPG','GIF','PNG'); 


    $i=0; 
    $open = opendir($dir); 
    // get each filename from directory 
    while (($file=readdir($open))!==false) { 
        // get extension 
        $ext=str_replace('.', '', strrchr($file, '.')); 
        // does it have a valid extension 
        if (in_array($ext, $allow))  
          $list[$i++]=$file; // store valid filename in array. use numerical indexing as makes it easier to display paginated images later 
    } 

    $perPage=20; // number of images to show per page 
    $total=count($list); // total number of images to show 
    $pages=ceil($total/$perPage); // number of pages is the number of images divided by how many per page 

    $thisPage=isset($_GET['pg'])?$_GET['pg']-1:0; // did user select a specific page? Note, pages on web are counted from 1 (not zero) so must subtract 1 for correct indexing 
    $start=$thisPage*$perPage; // calculate starting index into list of filenames 

    $perRow=2; // how many images to be shown on each row 

    // display quick index to pages. all pages except current page output as a link 
    print "Page "; 
    for ($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++) 
      if ($i==$thisPage) 
        print "&nbsp;".($i+1); 
      else 
        print "&nbsp;<a href='?pg=".($i+1)."'>".($i+1)."</a>"; 

    print "<tr>"; 
    $imgCnt=0; // used to count number of images displayed and hence whether to wrap page. note, could use "for" index $i but this is computationally quicker 
    for ($i=$start;$i<$start+$perPage;$i++) { 
      // may be too few images to fill page, so check if we have a valid array index. if we don't output empty table cell so fussy browsers 
      // don't mis-display table due to missing cells 
      if (isset($list[$i])) 
        print "<td><a target='_new' href='$dir$large{$list[$i]}'><img  style='height:180px;width:180px; border:2px solid black;  margin:20px 0px 10px  10px; *margin:10px 0px 10px 20px;' style='border-color:#000000 ' border='1' src='$dir{$list[$i]}'></a></td>"; 
      else 
        print "<td></td>"; 

      $imgCnt+=1; // increment images shown 
      if ($imgCnt%$perRow==0) // if image count divided by number to show per row has no remainder than it's time to wrap 
        print "</tr><tr>"; 
    } 
    print "</tr>"; 

    closedir($open); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should index your list on modify time and slice your array when you want to show them.

Update: you should use `krsort`

```
// the paths
$dir     = '/var/www/uploads/';
$urlPath = 'http://localhost/uploads/';

$allow   = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png', 'JPEG', 'JPG','GIF','PNG');
$open    = opendir($dir); 

while( $file = readdir( $open ) ){

  $ext = strtoupper( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

  if( in_array( $ext, $allow ) ){

    $modifyTime = filemtime( $dir . $file );
    $list[ $modifyTime ] = $file;

  }
}

# reverse sort on key
krsort( $list );

$perPage  = 20;
$total    = count($list);
$pages    = ceil($total/$perPage);
$thisPage = isset($_GET['pg'])?$_GET['pg']-1:0;
$start    = $thisPage*$perPage;

echo "Page "; 

// show pages
for ($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++):

  if ($i==$thisPage) :
    print "&nbsp;".($i+1); 
  else :
    print "&nbsp;<a href='?pg=".($i+1)."'>".($i+1)."</a>"; 
  endif;

endfor;

// show images
$items = array_slice( $list, $start, $perPage );
foreach( $items as $image ){
  echo "<br/> " . $image . "<br/>";
  echo "<a target='blank' href='" . $urlPath . $image . "'><img width='100' height='100' src='" . $urlPath . $image . "'/></a>";
  echo "<br/>";
}

closedir($open);
```

Read more on [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php)

Comment: Some errors were showing and one image is not also not showing but the rest of the image is find and seems to be assorted differently

Comment: its assorted differently but the recent images aren't being shown

Comment: @Eddie_ was using `arsort` instead of `krsort`. Try this updated code

Comment: it works, i just wish the images were clickable but thanks anyways

Comment: @Eddie_ you can wrap the `<img>` tags with `<a>` tags and they will be clickable :)

Comment: i tried but its either the images become unavailable or the image click is accessing the whole directory and not the image itself